# Data Members that Share State with Class

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

I've been running into an issue in a few contexts where a class contains an object that, while not being related in any terribly close manner, shares a significant amount of its state with another object. This is causing me some trouble since I am ending up with objects that are several times larger than they ought to be because of the overlapping state and, a couple times, I have encountered horrible bugs due to failing to properly keep the states locked together. I haven't been able to come up with a satisfactory answer to these issues, so am wondering if there are any C++ paradigms that deal with this sort of problem.

As a minimal example, suppose I have the following code, which basically models a psuedo-flow on a graph, keeping track of the excess at each node of the graph - and does so in a way that aggressively maintains the invariant that Node's excess is the sum of the flows into it minus the sum of the flows out of it:

```
struct Node{
    int excess = 0;
};
struct Flow{
    Node* const a;
    Node* const b;
    int flow = 0;
public:
    Flow(Node* a, Node* b):a(a),b(b){}
    void setFlow(int newFlow){
        int dif = newFlow - flow;
        a->excess -= dif;
        b->excess += dif;
        flow = newFlow;
    };
    ~Flow(){
        setFlow(0);
    }
};
```

At some later point in the code, there is another object that, among other things, interacts with the flow network in some complicated way where some pair of nodes is relevant to the class itself, but the interface to safely make a flow between them is also desirable. So, in code, we have some larger class that, somewhere in its definition, has the following snippets:

```
class UnrelatedObject{
    //...
    Node* const a;
    Node* const b;
    //...
    Flow f = {a,b};
    //...
};
```

The trouble is that this object is storing data redundantly - it has (barring programming errors!) an invariant that `a == f.a` and `b == f.b`. Ideally, I'd like to have some sort of template for `Flow` to which I can pass pointers to the members with the shared state as template arguments and which, otherwise, acts just like `Flow` does. The following code comes pretty close to doing what I want:

```
template<class T, Node* const T::* a, Node* const T::* b>
struct FlowLight{
    int flow = 0;
public:
    void setFlow(T* me, int newFlow){
        int dif = newFlow - flow;
        (me->*a)->excess -= dif;
        (me->*b)->excess += dif;
        flow = newFlow;
    }
    //Uh oh, we don't know the T* that owns this member in order to write the destructor!
};
```

Aside from the trouble with the destructor, one could then write

```
class UnrelatedObject{
    //...
    Node* const a;
    Node* const b;
    //...
    FlowLight<UnrelatedObject, &UnrelatedObject::a, &UnrelatedObject::b> f;
    //...
};
```

And this could even be made to function fully by adding a function of the signature `void cleanup(T*)` to the template and calling it in the destructor of `UnrelatedObject`, but this solution has the nasty habit to force destructors to be written for classes that, semantically, are not doing anything special at destruction (and leaves room to forget to clean something up and get bugs because of it!). However, it seems like there ought to be a way, given that, as in a normal class, the instantiations of such a template know that the data members are some constant offset away from the `this` pointer - I just don't see an obvious way to feed that kind of data through the type system at compile-time.

Is there an idiomatic way to deal with this sort of problem, where desired interfaces like `Flow` are somewhat uncoupled from the precise storage of data?

Comment: IMHO, this is a design issue. Usually, I try to prevent redundant data. This can be achieved by modeling e.g. a direct acyclic graph instead of a tree. `std::shared_ptr` is one tool to provide/grant sufficient life-time of that shared data. However, if data model is more complicated (e.g. multiple graphs for distinct relationships of the same base objects), the design can become really challenging and you will always pay for any advantage regarding one aspect with a penalty regarding another. (At least, that's my experience.)

Comment: Why not just drop the direct members and use `myUO.f.a` instead of `myUO.a` everywhere?

Comment: @DavisHerring The particular case I have in my code is a bit worse than what I literally describe here - for instance ```UnrelatedObject``` might want to have interfaces to multiple flows which have overlapping endpoints, or, as is the case in the actual code I am working on, there are a few interfaces like ```Flow``` that nicely model the semantics of the code and I want to be able to "compose" the interfaces into more meaningful classes - but this frequently involves those interfaces having overlapping data.